# "None so far" is this grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

A: do you have any questions?
B: None so far.

Is "none so far" a strange English and was it correct to use it in the dialogue above?.I was told by a native speaker that it is strange to use it this way in the dialogue.

Comment: No, it's perfectly normal, at least for this native speaker.

Comment: Me too. It's a very ordinary conversational example of reduction under repetition of the response _I have no questions so far_, which is completely ordinary and grammatical. _I have_ is understood from the question, _none_ is substituted for _no questions_, again from the question, and _so far_ is already an idiom. It could also be _Not so far_, from a different normal response.

Comment: Also visit ell.stackexchange.com and read the Q&A so far -- you may find that useful and informative.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's perfectly normal.  Granted, it's succinct and to the point, which is fine.  Made longer, though not necessarily better, it means

> "I have not one question so far."

Other options include

> - "I have no questions thus far."
> - "Questions?  No, none so far."
> - "I have none--yet."
> - "At this point, I have no questions."
> - "Not yet."
> - (in Yoda-speak):  "Of questions, I have none."